# transformation- in to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Input:

```
{ key : "value" ,
  list : [
    { 
        key : "values1" ,
        list : [
            { key : "value2" , list :[{ key : "simpleValue" } ]
            }
            ]
    },
    {
        key : "value3"
    }
]
}
```

Output:

{key : ["value" , "values1" , "values2" , "simpleeValue", "values3"]}

the code that I wrote for conversion is

```
var outputArray=new Array();
var count=0;
  function recursion(testData){



if(testData.key==undefined)
{

return ;

}


else
{
    outputArray[count]=testData.key;
    count++;

for(var k in testData.list)
    {

    testData1=testData.list[k];
    recursion(testData1);
    recursion(testData.key);
    }


}

return outputArray;
}
```

The output will only give me the value list an array,like [
 'value',
 'values1',
 'value2',
 'simpleValue',
 'value3'
],  how do I use the hash method to get the correct output?

Comment: You mean: { key: ["value", "values1", "values3"] } ?

Comment: I don't understand, what you want to do... why do you want to hash and for what?

Comment: Is it possible to get an output in the format { key: ["value", "values1", "values3"] }  from my input??

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Why would you need a hash function to return an object?

Comment: You want all values inside that list? or can you structure your input & output properly with meaningful context?

Comment: I ve structured my code properly... yes I want all values in to one array

Comment: Since I could nt answer as I am a rookie, Ive added the solution to the bottom part of the question..

Comment: Okay... that's what my solution said ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this thing sorted out

```
var outputArray=new Array();

function recursion(testData){


if(testData.key==undefined)
{

return ;

}


else
{

    //alert(testData.key);
    outputArray.push(testData.key);

for(var k in testData.list)
    {
    testData1=testData.list[k];
    recursion(testData1);
    recursion(testData.key);
    }


}


var l={};
l.key=outputArray;
return l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, something like this??

```
var inpObj = { key : "value" ,list : [
                    {
                        key : "values1"
                    },
                    {
                        key : "value3"
                    }
                ]
            };

var outputObj = new Object;
var outputArray = new Array();

function recursion(testData){
    if(testData.key==undefined)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var newKey={};
        //alert(testData.key);
        outputArray.push(testData.key);

        for(var k in testData.list)
        {
            testData1=testData.list[k];
            recursion(testData1);
            recursion(testData.key);
        }
    }

    return outputArray;
}

recursion(inpObj);
if (outputObj.key == undefined) outputObj.key = outputArray;
alert(outputObj.key.join(", "));
```

Comment: Which error do you get? I've got an Object with key as "key" and the key has an array with values. { key: [] }

Comment: hmm... look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/AhrWU/   it works fine... i think, you've got a copy&paste error... check your code!